# Error when retrieving from my xml document using xquery

Tags: java, xml, xquery

I am trying to retrieve the authors from my XML documents but some of the authors have apostrophe's in their names so the results throw an error.

#### Input:

```
<dblp>
    <book mdate="2002-01-03" key="books/aw/CeriF97">
        <author>Stefano Ceri</author>
        <author>Piero Fraternali</author>
        <title>Designing Database Applications with Objects and Rules: The IDEA Methodology</title>
        <publisher href="db/publishers/aw.html">Addison-Wesley</publisher>
        <year>1997</year>
        <isbn>0-201-40369-2</isbn>
    </book>
</dblp>
```

#### Java/XQuery Code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getArrayListOfAuthors(){

    String query = "for $x in fn:distinct-values(doc(\"" +xml_file_name+ "\")//author) " +
                    "order by $x "+
                    "return $x";

    System.out.println("XQuery query:"+query);
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
        XQConnection conn = ds.getConnection();
        XQExpression exp = conn.createExpression();

        XQSequence seq = exp.executeQuery(query);
        int i = 1;

        while (seq.next()) {
            i++;
            //System.out.println(seq.getAtomicValue());
                            myList.add(seq.getAtomicValue());
        }
        //System.out.println("\n== Total number of authors is "+i+" ==");

        seq.close();

    } catch (XQException err) {
    System.out.println("Failed as expected: " + err.getMessage());
    }
              return myList;
}
```

#### Error Message:

```
XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #...e $y/author = 'Kieran O'Neill'#:
    Unmatched quote in expression
Error on line 1 column 109
```

Comment: Include a sample of your XML, and the full exception stack trace.

Comment: This is a sample of my XML code
<dblp>
<book mdate="2002-01-03" key="books/aw/CeriF97">
    <author>Stefano Ceri</author>
    <author>Piero Fraternali</author>
    <title>Designing Database Applications with Objects and Rules: The IDEA Methodology</title>
    <publisher href="db/publishers/aw.html">Addison-Wesley</publisher>
    <year>1997</year>
    <isbn>0-201-40369-2</isbn>
</book>

Comment: Your error mentions `$y/author`, but your XQuery doesn't have that. Can you include all of the XQuery?

Answer (score 3):

The error message strongly suggests that you are constructing a query by string concatenation, perhaps by processing the list of authors obtained from the query you have shown us. (Look for a query containing $y, which isn't the one in your sample).

Then change it so that instead of constructing a query using concatenation like this:

query = "//author[@name="' + name + "']"

you construct the query to contain a parameter:

query = "declare variable $name external; //author[@name=$name]"

and execute this supplying the value of $name as a run-time parameter. There are several benefits apart from avoiding the problem of names containing apostrophes: you avoid the security problems of injection attacks, and you get a performance benefit because you can compile the query once and use it repeatedly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What I want to get is an arraylist of all authors in my xml document. Here is a sample of the XML document
<dblp>
<book mdate="2002-01-03" key="books/aw/CeriF97">
    <author>Stefano Ceri</author>
    <author>Piero Fraternali</author>Wesley</publisher>
</book>
<book mdate="2002-01-03" key="books/bc/BatiniCN92">
    <author>Carlo Batini</author>
    <author>Stefano Ceri</author>
    <author>Shamkant B. Navathe</author>
    <title>Conceptual Database Design: An Entity-Relationship Approach.</title>
    <isbn>0-8053-0244-1</isbn>
</book>

Comment: Which part don't you understand? You haven't shown us the query that is responsible for the error message.